# MySQL InnoDB Full-Text Search

Tags: php, mysql, search, relevance

I've been trying to workout a method of achieving full-text search without installing a server level piece of software.

I've read various posts throughout Stack Overflow which suggest applications such as Sphinx. However, the application I am writing is a PHP application which is deployed automatically to a chosen server and I don't want the reliance of a server level application.

Are there any PHP libraries, MySQL functions which are able to do this?

I am happy with the result set my current standard MySQL LIKE query returns, I am more seeking to resolve the issue of ordering the results by relevance.

Comment: You can use MyISAM and a separate table for that data, you can tie them together using triggers.  Or upgrade to MySql 5.6 that supports fulltext for INNODB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fulltext search with InnoDB in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337294/fulltext-search-with-innodb-in-mysql)